# R assign the output from a function to a variable

Tags: r, assign

I want to condunct function which is similar to SAS of which the name of macro variable could be easily added with the other character.

But, I cannot do it in R right now, for example, in the following syntax, I want to create a function which just obtain the mean for some variable and assign a new name for the variable.

```
sex=c(1,2,3)

rf<-function(x){
    assign(paste("x", "mean",sep=""),mean(x))
    }
rf(sex)
```

I want to get a new variable "sexmean" whose value is mean(1,2,3).

How could I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this using functional programming (and R) is to do:

```
sexmean <- mean(sex)
```

If you really really want to have a function with the side effect of changing a global variable (this is *very bad practice in R* and functional programming in general) this will work (but is *highly* discouraged):

```
sex <- c(1,2,3)

rf <-function(x){
  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  assign(paste(arg_name, "mean",sep=""), mean(x), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

rf(sex)
```

Comment: Why do you not show how to do this the proper way in R?

Comment: @Roland, I completely agree with your recommendation to learn functional programming and that the proper FP/R solution is sexmean <- mean(sex).